# How to infer return type based on parameter type

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to figure out how to type this function so that the four "tests" after it work. I've been trying various combinations of function overloads and conditional types (which I don't really understand), and tried looking into `infer` (which I *really* don't understand), but I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
export function parse<T = unknown>(value: string | null): T {
                     // Can't figure out what to put here ^
  return typeof value === 'string' ? JSON.parse(value) : null
}

const a = parse<string>('"test"') // a is string
const b = parse<string>(null)     // b is string, but should be null
const c = parse('"test"')         // c is unknown
const d = parse(null)             // d is unknown, but should be null

const json = window.localStorage.getItem('foobar')
const e = parse<string>(json)     // e is string, but should be string | null
```

The following, using overloads, corrects the typing for the first 4 cases:

```
export function parse<T = unknown>(value: string): T;
export function parse<T = unknown>(value: null): null;
export function parse<T = unknown>(value: string | null): T | null {
  return typeof value === 'string' ? JSON.parse(value) : null;
}

const a = parse<string>('"test"') // a is string
const b = parse<string>(null)     // b is null
const c = parse('"test"')         // c is unknown
const d = parse(null)             // d is null
```

*But* it doesn't allow me to pass in a value that might be either `string` *or* `null`, like in the case of `e`:

```
const json = window.localStorage.getItem('foobar') // json is string | null
const e = parse<string>(json)
                     // ^^^^ Error: No overload matches this call.
```

How can I type the return type of the function in a way that both passes my four "tests" *and* it allows me to pass in a value that might be either, like in the example above?

Comment: Updated the question with what I tried, and the error I'm getting.

Comment: Yeah, I've kind of guessed that I need to use conditional types, so I've tried to read up on it, but just can't seem to figure out how to do it. 

Comment: FYI: `typeof` is a Javascript operator which will never return "unknown" as it isn't related to TS. I am aware you may know this but it aids in avoiding confusion to not use this when talking about the TS type.

Comment: @IngoBürk Good point. To avoid confusion for others later, I replaced `typeof` in the question. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only declaring 2 overloads:

```
export function parse<T = unknown>(value: string): T;
export function parse<T = unknown>(value: null): null;
```

Not 3, as the next line is the function implementation:

```
export function parse<T = unknown>(value: string | null): T | null { ... }
```

Therefore, you can call this `parse` function with an `string` `value` or a `null` `value`, but not with something that could be `string | null`, which is what `window.localStorage.getItem(...)` returns.

So basically, you are just missing one more overload, which actually matches the signature of the implementation:

```
export function parse<T = unknown>(value: string): T;
export function parse<T = unknown>(value: null): null;
export function parse<T = unknown>(value: string | null): T | null;
export function parse<T = unknown>(value: string | null): T | null {
  return typeof value === 'string' ? JSON.parse(value) : null;
}
```

Here you can see all 3 overloads in action:

```
const overloadOne = parse(''); // unknown
const overloadOneTyped = parse<string>(''); // string
const overloadTwo = parse(null); // null
const overloadThree = parse<string>(window.localStorage.getItem('foobar')); // string | null

const json = window.localStorage.getItem('foobar'); // string | null
const value = parse<string>(json); // string | null
```

Comment: Ooooh! That makes sense, and totally worked!

Out of curiosity though, would it be possible to write this same thing, without overloads, using conditional typing instead? 

Comment: I don't think so and in any case, I would favour overloads as they are more readable, but maybe someone else can come up with a solution with conditional types.

Comment: Usually overloaded functions can be turned into generic functions with conditional typed arguments/return types.   In this case, the overloaded function is already generic, with a type parameter that needs to be manually specified.  The conditional type version would therefore need two generic type parameters, one of which you need to specify, and one you want the compiler to infer.  But there's no "partial type parameter inference" in the language, so you'd either need to specify both or infer both or some other workaround, making this even less appealing than the overload solution, imo.

Comment: @Svish Not sure if this resolved your issue, but I would appreciate if you could accept / upvote if it did. 